# Combine excel sheets from different files with BytesIO using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, bytesio

I am using pandas library to combine excel sheets into bytesIO memory, from different files, and write them to another combined sheets excel file as follows:

```
# Bucket
output = io.BytesIO()
bucket = "MYBUCKET"
filepath = "test.xlsx"

# dir
current_dir = os.getcwd()
root_path = current_dir.replace("/src", "")

# logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s -> [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)


def get_sheet_names(path):
    # Returns all sheet names
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
    return xls.sheet_names


def add_sheets(metadata_path, sample_path):
    filename = sample_path.split("/")[-1]
    filename_slugify = f"_metadata_{filename.lower()}_{date.today()}.xlsx"

    # create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
    logger.info(f"root path: {root_path}")
    output_path = f"{root_path}/{filename_slugify}"
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine='xlsxwriter')


    # Metadata
    metadata_sheets = get_sheet_names(metadata_path)
    logger.info(f"Metadata sheets: {metadata_sheets}")
    for i, sheet in enumerate(metadata_sheets):
        logger.info(f"Sheet number '{i+1}' is in progress: {sheet}")

        df = pd.read_excel(metadata_path, sheet_name=i, header=None)  # Create dataframe from sheet

        # write each DataFrame to a specific sheet
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=False)

    # Sample data
    sample_sheets = get_sheet_names(sample_path)
    logger.info(f"Sample data sheets: {sample_sheets}")
    for i, sheet in enumerate(sample_sheets):
        logger.info(f"Sheet number '{i+1}' is in progress: {sheet}")

        df = pd.read_excel(sample_path, sheet_name=i, header=None)  # Create dataframe from sheet

        # write each DataFrame to a specific sheet
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=False)

    logger.info(f'{output_path} \n Exporting {filename_slugify}...')
    writer.save()
    output.seek(0)
    logger.info(f"Adding level value for '{filename}' has finished.")
    
    data = output.getvalue()
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=filepath, Body=data)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_sheets("s3://" + "MYBUCKET" + f"METADATAFILE_PATH",
               "s3://" + "MYBUCKET" + f"SAMPLEDATAFILE_PATH")
```

The output file comes empty, with no data or sheets, when debugging the dataframes, I see the read operations are working well, the writer is the one who missing somthing.

Comment: Hey David, this looks like a lot of code. Is it all necessary to reproduce the problem? Can you isolate more narrowly the code that's generating the actual issue?

Comment: Can you try `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, mode='a', engine='xlsxwriter')`? The default argument for `mode` is `'w'` meaning write, so the file is empty because maybe because your last df is empty?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.